# How can I prevent XState node from resetting it's child parallel states when receiving an event?

Tags: javascript, state-machine, state-management, xstate

I was exploring the XState world and tried to recreate the machine [@davidkpiano](https://twitter.com/DavidKPiano) mentioned in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiT4Q1ntvzg&ab_channel=ReactNext&t=29m)

And faced an issue with doing the transitions right. When I send a message to parent machine, it resets all the child machines.

For example: I expect the machine to be in **dirty** and **focused** state after I fire the **CHANGE** and **FOCUS** event one after another. But after sending **FOCUS** message the pristine state resets back to **pristine**.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/statelyai/xstate/issues/400), but multiple transitions do the same thing (as it actually described in the issue itself)

Also, **I don't want to store all the information** about pristine, focused and touched state **into the context**, because it will not be as safe as doing it with state machines.

The code below is copy-pastable into https://xstate.js.org/viz/

```js
const createPristineMachineConfig = (inputName) => {
  return {
    id: `${inputName}.pristine`,
    initial: 'pristine',
    states: {
      pristine: {
        on: {
          [`${inputName}.CHANGE`]: 'dirty',
        },
      },
      dirty: {
        type: 'final',
      },
    },
  };
};

const createTouchedConfig = (inputName) => {
  return {
    id: `${inputName}.touched`,
    initial: 'untouched',
    states: {
      untouched: {
        on: {
          [`${inputName}.TOUCH`]: 'touched',
        },
      },
      touched: {
        type: 'final',
      },
    },
  };
};

const createFocusedMachineConfig = (inputName) => {
  return {
    id: `${inputName}.focused`,
    initial: 'blurred',
    states: {
      blurred: {
        on: {
          [`${inputName}.FOCUS`]: 'focused',
        },
      },
      focused: {
        on: {
          [`${inputName}.BLUR`]: 'blurred',
        },
      },
    },
  };
};

const createInputMachineConfig = (inputName) => ({
  id: inputName,
  type: 'parallel',
  context: {
    value: '',
  },
  on: {
    FOCUS: {
      actions: send(`${inputName}.FOCUS`),
      internal: true,
    },
    BLUR: {
      actions: [send(`${inputName}.TOUCH`), send(`${inputName}.BLUR`)],
      internal: true,
    },
    CHANGE: {
      actions: [assign((ctx, event) => ({ ...ctx, value: event.payload.value })), send(`${inputName}.CHANGE`)],
      internal: true,
    },
  },
  states: {
    pristine: createPristineMachineConfig(inputName),
    touched: createTouchedConfig(inputName),
    focused: createFocusedMachineConfig(inputName),
  },
});

const loginInputMachine = Machine(createInputMachineConfig('login'));
```

Comment: Couldn't solve it myself, but here are some ideas that you could try out:
As you already saw in the GH issue the parallel states are probably reset with their initial state when the whole machine receives an event. You could give history states a try. And maybe try specifying target states directly instead of using the `send()` function. The usage of a dynamic value for ids of the machine and child states seems a bit excessive to me. You could simplify it by using hard-coded values. Could be possible that events are sent to the whole machine instead of sub-states by accident; not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that happens because `dirty` is a final state, for example:

```
{
  id: 'loginForm',
  initial: 'idle',
  context: {
    error: undefined,
  },
  invoke: [
    {
      id: 'usernameInput',
      src: inputMachine,
    },
    {
      id: 'passwordInput',
      src: inputMachine,
    },
    {
      id: 'loginButton',
      src: buttonMachine,
    },
  ],
  states: {
    idle: {
    },
    processing: {

    },
    finished: {
    },
    failed: {
    },
  },
};
```

I have this machine which spawns some actors, and I can access through `loginForm` machine in the following way `loginForm.state.children.usernamInput`, but if one of those machines have reach a final state it returns undefined.